# How can I use several form inputs with the same name?

Tags: php, html, forms, query-string, html-input

I have several checkbox (I don't know number of them) that create from a loop in a form.

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="id">
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="id">
...//create in a loop
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="id">
</form>
```

My question is that How can I read them, If I use `<?php $_REQUEST['id']; ?>`, it only reads the last checkbox.

Comment: What's the use ? They all got the same value. Anyway, you can use an array of name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an input array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="id_a">
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="id_b">
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="id_c">
<!--                           ^^ this makes it an array -->
```

`$_REQUEST['id']` can be accessed:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['id'] as $id)
{
    echo $id;
}
```

Outputs

> id_a
>   id_b
>   id_c

Side note: this works with `$_POST` and `$_GET` (not just `$_REQUEST`). Generally speaking though `$_REQUEST` should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Wow I never knew you can do that! Does this method works with other server side languages? Is it W3 standard?

Comment: @Stasel, Yes this is a standard and is server-side language agnostic so is supported by all modern server-side languages. If you find it is not supported in a language, you can simply create a parser for it because the browser sends the raw data like `id[]=a,id[]=b,id[]=c` and so would be easy to read in any language so long as you have access to the raw post/get data.

Answer (score -4):

Use unique id's for your checkboxes, e.g.,

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="id1" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" name="id2" value="value2">
...//create in a loop
<input type="checkbox" name="id3" value="value3">
</form>
```

Comment: @Ehsan This example is not the way you should be using. You will have to validate each ID individually, the example posted by MyCode is what you should be using

Comment: This would work but it requires a lot of unnecessary work because you have to make sure the `name`'s are unique, then on the server side you have to loop the data array and search the key for `id` to determine if it's one of the values.

Comment: @Ehsan, depending on what's generating your HTML, you could use the unique identifiers as I provided, e.g., `name="id${i}"` in PHP.